# Can I prevent a search in one window from falling through to all windows

Tags: search, vim, highlighting

I have search highlighting turned on for Vim. If I have a terminal mode Vim split into different windows (displaying different files) and do a search in one, the search falls through to all the open windows and buffers and all occurrences of the search term are highlighted in all windows. Is it possible to restrict this to *only* the currently active window, with each window and buffer having its own effective search and highlighting?

Answer (score 2):

What about making `match` group and highlight it. For example

```
:highlight TEST ctermbg=grey guibg=grey
:match TEST /TODO/
```

The example creates match group `TEST` and highlight it with terminal background and gui background set to `grey`. This is just the idea, you can come up with many clever tricks around it.

`:match` has limitation, so you might like to read `:help :match`

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to highlighting could be the quickfix list.  If you use `vimgrep /pattern/ %` where `%` is the current buffer, then only search results from that buffer will appear in the quicklist.  `:cnext` to jump through if you don't have Tim Pope [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) plugin.

Drew Neil explains this really well in his [screencast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-multiple-files-with-vimgrep/).

Or the `Location List`, such as::

```
nnoremap <leader>* :lvim /<c-r>=expand("<cword>")<cr>/ %<cr>:lopen<cr>
```